# Change the size of a card in Gallery view of a List

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I've been trying to change the card size in a list gallery view. It doesn't seem to accept the height and width of the cards displays as its default size. Is there something I'm missing or might be getting in the way?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": "250",
  "width": "500",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@group.fieldData",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "22px",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "display": "flex",
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "border-radius": "6px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "margin": "1px 4px 4px 1px",
        "background-color": "=if(@group.fieldData == 'Done', '#CAF0CC', if (@group.fieldData == 'Cancelled', '#FABBC3', if(@group.fieldData == 'In Progress', '#D4E7F6', if (@group.fieldData == 'Proposed', '#FFEBC0',  ''))))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can word wrap the header. Just add in-line styling to include “white-space”: “normal” and “word-break”: “keep-all” “display”: “inline-block” or “display”: “flex” “position”: “relative”

Answer (score 0):

You can only adjust the gallery view if you provide the `formatter` value to determine what the card content should be. Adjusting your format from above you can see things in action like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": "250",
  "width": "500",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "Wowee!",
    "style": {
      "background-color": "tan"
    }
  },
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@group.fieldData",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "22px",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "display": "flex",
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "border-radius": "6px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "margin": "1px 4px 4px 1px",
        "background-color": "=if(@group.fieldData == 'Done', '#CAF0CC', if (@group.fieldData == 'Cancelled', '#FABBC3', if(@group.fieldData == 'In Progress', '#D4E7F6', if (@group.fieldData == 'Proposed', '#FFEBC0',  ''))))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you are expecting that the card view that's shown by default will show up there, you'll need to remove your format and then adjust the design view of the card (do literally anything), then switch to Advanced mode. All the JSON will be there and you can merge your format into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to **Advanced mode** to check all JSON of Gallery view formatting

**Please following steps:**

1.On the Gallery view, click "**Format current view**"

[image]

2.On the Format view windows, click "**Edit card**"

[image]

3.On the Card Designer windows, click "**Advanced mode**"

[image]

4.You can change the value of "**height**" and "**width**"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to word-wrap the title?

Comment: Hi Solbadguy. I don’t think it’s possible to word wrap the column header. Since SharePoint modern experience doesn’t support customization with master page.  Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/269381/can-we-word-wrap-the-column-titles-inside-list-vie.html